# Wonder vs imagine

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I had a student who said:

> I can't **wonder** what the world will be like when my grandson is 21.

In this sentence I'm pretty sure we should use *imagine*, but I couldn't succinctly explain why and now I'm not even sure if *wonder* is actually wrong here or just weird.

I ended up saying that while there is some overlap in meaning between *imagine* and *wonder*, they are not entirely interchangeable and are used in different contexts.

Is there a better way of explaining the differences between the words?

Comment: You may want to instruct the student on clarity. If you are having trouble with that sentence then it could certainly benefit from a more concrete word. "Imagine" would be more a more a active verb. "Prognosticate" is another accurate word for considering future events.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the word following "wonder" is a question word, and the word following "imagine" is "that." I wonder what he will say; I imagine that he will say yes. I wonder where my wallet is; I imagine that it is under the bed. I wonder how he will do on the test; I imagine that he will do well. This illustrates that we "wonder" a question and "imagine" an answer. Your student means that he can ask what the world will be like, but he cannot answer that question; he wonders what it will be like, but he cannot imagine it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I understand your source of confusion. If he said "I wonder what the world will be like when my grandson is 21", it would sound more natural. If he said "I can't imagine what the world will be like when my grandson is 21", that would also sound natural. It seems like the using of "can't" with "wonder" threw you off.

It sounds unnatural because you can't "can't wonder". Wonder is defined, in his case, as the act of **trying** to imagine something. If you can't form pictures of a scenario in your head, then you can't imagine that scenario. But the act of trying to imagine it is in itself wondering. He **can** indeed wonder. So his saying "I can't wonder" is wrong because he **can** wonder. In fact, just thinking about the scenario itself is an act of wondering. He needs to say "I can't imagine" because it is the imagining that he is having trouble with, not the wondering which he is already doing.